# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

Here what i got when compile the project

by this command

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.classPathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=trident.myproject
```

got this

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: storm/trident/state/StateFactory
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2670)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1603)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:285)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: storm.trident.state.StateFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 6 more

INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO]   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An exception occured while executing the Java class. storm/trident  /state/StateFactory

storm.trident.state.StateFactory
```

i reviewed the folder and can't find this class ! although i ran it before successfully

i wrote pom file as parts

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

part 2 of pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>colt</groupId>
        <artifactId>colt</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

part 3 of pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>twitter4j-stream</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.17</version>
            </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: is it a warning or an error?

Comment: You should edit your question and post your pom.xml

Comment: It is unclear what exactly do you ask about - class not found, you confirm that indeed it is not there, everything as expected. You can probably also guess the solution - add the class correctly, or remove your dependency on it.

Comment: Is the class `storm.trident.state.StateFactory` part of your project? Or is it part of a dependency?

Comment: Thanks for you , i edited the post it's error , i'm new to maven so unfamiliar with error and can't know what dependency should i add !

Comment: i followed this path storm.trident.state.StateFactory but can't find storm.trident.state.StateFactory !

Comment: i tried to post the pom but couldn't ... tried to part the code but couldn't too ... !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have changed the scope of the dependency in your pom.xml file. If your container is providing the dependency change scope to provided.
`<scope>provided</scope>`

If container is not providing the dependency change scope to compile.
`<scope>compile</scope>`

Comment: i found this <dependency>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: is it for Apache storm? How you are using the Apache storm in your project? Find the dependency for Apache storm in pom.xml file.

Comment: Please check whether storm dependency is downloaded or not? You can check it in local maven repository. If it is not downloaded run the maven command with `-U` flag, to download forcefully.

Comment: i added pom file in the post . i'm new to maven and storm too , that what you talking about <dependency>
            <groupId>storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Comment: Add `<scope>compile</scope>` instead of `<scope>provided</scope>`

Comment: really many many many thanks to you , i'm on this error all the day THANKS but waht is the difference between provided and compile ?

Comment: For detailed information please look at the **Dependency Scope** section on this link https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: i'm now facing new problem after this update SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/st/storm-0.8.2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/st/workspace/myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Found multiple defaults.yaml resources.

Comment: i searched for the solution and found that i should add <scope>provided </scope> !!

Comment: You have to exclude SLF4J dependency if it is included multiple times. You can search for dependency exclusion in maven. Using eclipse, you can identify which  libraries are including SLF4J. Just keep one and add exclusion for other libraries.

Comment: pom doesn't have any SLF4J so should i add it ? or i should add jar of slf4j too using eclipse?

Comment: Some of the jar may be adding SLF4J dependency implicitly. So check which jars are adding SLF4J. If there are multiple jars referring to SLF4J jar then those many times SLF4J is added in class path. There may be different versions. You only need to exclude SLF4J.

Comment: i found those in library of storm slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar

Comment: You can exclude `slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar` from storm dependency.

Comment: If it is a new error or issue you can create new question. So it can be discussed separately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356292/found-multiple-defaults-yaml-resources

Comment: this error made another error appeared ! when i returned provided i get error again !!