# Found multiple defaults.yaml resources

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

when i tried to submit the topology i found this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Found multiple defaults.yaml resources. You're probably bundling the Storm jars with your topology jar.
at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:115)
at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.readDefaultConfig(Utils.java:135)
at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:155)
at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:61)
at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:40)
at trident.myproject.main(myproject.java:288)
```

But this error appeared after updated in pom.xml by

`<scope>compile</scope> instead of <scope>provided</scope>`

that because i was an error

```
An exception occured while executing the Java class. storm/trident/state/StateFactory
```

here pom file

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>trident.myproject</mainClass>
                    <!-- <mainClass>crawler.Crawler</mainClass> -->
                </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
```

part 2 of pom file

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

part 3 of pom file

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: It seems that your jar still contains `defaults.yaml`. Did you try `mvn clean` before packaging? How do you package your jar? Maybe you need to exclude the file explicitly.

Comment: yes i tried mvn clean now the pom file of the project contains <scope>provided</scope> and tried to use this command mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.classPathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=trident.TheProject and the result is An exception occured while executing the Java class. storm/trident/state/StateFactory

Comment: Can you post the error message/stack trace? Did you try to submit via `storm jar myJarFile.jar package.and.MyMainClass`?

Comment: yes , i used storm jar target/jarfile.jar trident.class topology name but i've a question i tried to run project in local mode by using mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.classPathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=trident.class then error appeared "An exception occured while executing the Java class. storm/trident/state/StateFactory" someone advised me to change scope of pom file from provided to compile and it' worked well then got the above error when tried to submit the topology ! but the project and coder didn't change in the scope so the error in finding statefactory

Comment: the previous error here in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33343686/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror/33344743?noredirect=1#comment54508105_33344743

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference in running a topology in `LocalCluster` or remotely via `StormSubmitter` (which is the default setting in the project).

The scope of `storm-core` is set to `<scope>provided</scope>` be the default because those class files are available in the cluster anyway. `provided` tells maven, that those classes must not be included in the `jar` file that is assembled, thus reducing the size of the jar. Furthermore, this avoids conflicts if files are provided multiple times -- that is what happens with `default.yaml` if you change the scope to `compile`. For those case, all files from `storm-core` are packaged into you `jar` and submitted to the cluster. Storm finds the file `defaults.yaml` "locally" (ie, locally on the worker machine in the cluster) and in your `jar`. Thus, Storm does not know which one to use and raises an error.

However, `provided` excludes those class files if you run locally, too. Of course, locally those files are not available automatically but must be included in *CLASSPATH* when starting up the local JVM. As `provided` excludes the files from `storm-core` you get the `ClassNotFound` exception.

As an alternative to change the scope each time you want to submit to a different environment, you can set the scope to `compile` and include your topology Main/Bolt/Spout classes explicitly in your `maven-jar-plugin` settings. This explicit inclusion automatically excludes all other files from the jar, ie, all files from `storm-core`.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>

  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>MyTopology</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <includes>
          <include>my/topology/package/**/*.class</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation i'll try it now

Comment: so part 2 of pom file that should i change it ? i posted parts of pom file

Comment: Use `maven-jar-plugin` instead of `maven-assembly-plugin` or exclude `storm-core` via `<dependencySet>`: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/including-and-excluding-artifacts.html

Comment: i changed to maven-jar-plugin but have error build when used mvn clean " 'single' was specified in an execution, but not found in the plugin " in the part 2 of pom i posted

Comment: Just look at am answer. Goal must be `jar`; not `single`.

Comment: ok now should i add <includes>
          <include>my/topology/package/**/*.class</include>
        </includes> but can't get what is in include tag ? i'm sorry for my lot questions

Comment: Include all your Bolt and Spout classes of your topology. And your class that contains the `main` method and plugs the topology together. If you use additional libraries, you need to include those, too. You can use `**` are recursive wildcards to include hole packages and sub-packages. Have a look into the maven-jar-plugin documentation for further details.

Comment: i read about how to include jar into pom but what i got to write the path of the topology ! isn't right?

Comment: what about this tag  <packagingIncludes> ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: i mean what should i write in this tag like that <include>/path/of/topology.jar</include> that what i got form examples and i'm asking too about this tag <packagingIncludes> i found it and don't know if it can help or not

Comment: Using the <include> tag, you list the classes that should be packaged into a jar (the path is relative to folder `target/classes`, ie, if you have a class `A.java` of package `a.b.c` you specify `a/b/c/A.class`. Thus, class `A.class` is added to the jar file. No clue about <packagingIncludes> tag.

Comment: finally i accept your answer without any other problem , Thanks for your helping

Comment: Glad that it works for you now and that I could help :)