# Found multiple defaults.yaml resources. You're probably bundling the Storm jars with your topology jar

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

So i updated the question and the title now because now i know the problem.
This is the worker log, I know there are lots of questions like this one ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356292/found-multiple-defaults-yaml-resources)) but I can't get any of the solutions to work whatever I do.

> Edit: It's the same problem as the mentioned in the link but with
>   different cause as mentioned in the answer below.

This is the worker log.

```
2016-06-23 00:10:56.115 STDERR [INFO] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2016-06-23 00:10:56.122 STDERR [INFO]   at org.apache.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:78)
2016-06-23 00:10:56.124 STDERR [INFO]   at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker$_main.invoke(worker.clj:768)
2016-06-23 00:10:56.124 STDERR [INFO]   at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:165)
2016-06-23 00:10:56.124 STDERR [INFO]   at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
2016-06-23 00:10:56.125 STDERR [INFO]   at org.apache.storm.daemon.worker.main(Unknown Source)
2016-06-23 00:10:56.125 STDERR [INFO] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Found multiple defaults.yaml resources. You're probably bundling the Storm jars with your topology jar. [jar:file:/media/bishoymak/All/College/New%20GP/Second/Programs/storm/lib/storm-core-1.0.1.jar!/defaults.yaml, jar:file:/media/bishoymak/All/College/New%20GP/Second/Programs/storm/storm-local/supervisor/stormdist/LogAnalyserStorm-1-1466632686/stormjar.jar!/defaults.yaml]
2016-06-23 00:10:56.126 STDERR [INFO]   at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:307)
2016-06-23 00:10:56.126 STDERR [INFO]   at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.readDefaultConfig(Utils.java:351)
2016-06-23 00:10:56.127 STDERR [INFO]   at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:387)
2016-06-23 00:10:56.127 STDERR [INFO]   at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:119)
2016-06-23 00:10:56.127 STDERR [INFO]   ... 5 more
2016-06-23 00:10:56.128 STDERR [INFO] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Found multiple defaults.yaml resources. You're probably bundling the Storm jars with your topology jar. [jar:file:/media/bishoymak/All/College/New%20GP/Second/Programs/storm/lib/storm-core-1.0.1.jar!/defaults.yaml, jar:file:/media/bishoymak/All/College/New%20GP/Second/Programs/storm/storm-local/supervisor/stormdist/LogAnalyserStorm-1-1466632686/stormjar.jar!/defaults.yaml]
```

and here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>StormExample</groupId>
  <artifactId>StormExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source/>
          <target/>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>

          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>LogAnalyserStorm</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <includes>
                  <include>LogAnalyserStorm.class</include>
              <include>FakeCallLogReaderSpout.class</include>
              <include>CallLogCounterBolt.class</include>
              <include>CallLogCreatorBolt.class</include>
                </includes>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
    <repositories> 
      <repository> 
        <id>clojars.org</id> 
        <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url> 
      </repository> 
    </repositories> 
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I used mvn jar:jar and mvn package but it always includes the storm core although i am stating that it only includes the 4 classes to include, so please tell me what am I doing wrong.

and here is my topology code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
          //Create Config instance for cluster configuration
          Config config = new Config();
          config.setDebug(true);

          TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
          builder.setSpout("call-log-reader-spout", new FakeCallLogReaderSpout());

          builder.setBolt("call-log-creator-bolt", new CallLogCreatorBolt())
             .shuffleGrouping("call-log-reader-spout");

          builder.setBolt("call-log-counter-bolt", new CallLogCounterBolt())
             .fieldsGrouping("call-log-creator-bolt", new Fields("call"));

          System.setProperty("storm.jar", "/media/bishoymak/All/College/New GP/Second/Programs/storm/lib/storm-core-1.0.1.jar");
          StormSubmitter.submitTopology("LogAnalyserStorm", config, builder.createTopology());
```

Comment: Did you check the logs files for error messages? You can also enable debug mode (via the Config you give to StormSubmitter) to get more information in the logs. Can you add your topology building code?

Comment: I did and unfortunately i didn't update the question yet, please re-check and help if you can, Thank you.

Comment: I just realized you are the same person that posted the solution on the mentioned, so please check what i am doing wrong in the pom.xml or if i am building wrong, thanks and sorry for duplication.

Comment: Did you try `mvn clean package` ? Maybe your jar is not build because it is already there...

Comment: Yeah I did, but it's the same error again

Comment: I did manually remove defaults.yaml from the worker jar, it launched but now i get [ERROR] Error on initialization of server mk-worker

Comment: I just looked at your code. This line seems to be wrong:           System.setProperty("storm.jar", "/media/bishoymak/All/College/New GP/Second/Programs/storm/lib/storm-core-1.0.1.jar");
It would point to the jar that is assembled by maven-jar-pluing and not to storm-core.

Comment: Exactly exactly, i just discovered it after i almost had nothing in my pom.xml and it still included it, after i deleted that line it worked so i came to update, Thank you again for your answers through the other questions it helped me a ton, feel free to add it as answer and i will mark it.

Comment: Well. This question is a duplicate. Just delete it.

Comment: Glad it works now. :)

Comment: I will :D but the thing is some people might run into this problem, so i feel obligated to put an answer :D, unfortunately i still lack reputation to up vote sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Found multiple defaults.yaml resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356292/found-multiple-defaults-yaml-resources)

Comment: yeah i know that's where i tried to up vote you xD, but that's a different solution to the problem, i had that link for about 3 days and i was smh till i removed that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That problem had to do nothing about the pom.xml just remove this line

```
System.setProperty("storm.jar", "/media/bishoymak/All/College/New GP/Second/Programs/storm/lib/storm-core-1.0.1.jar");
```

Comment: It's better if you can elaborate. Why did this fix the problem?